# How to select last non-NULL columns in a set

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am creating a table that has a series of revisions for each logical row, and uses the NULL value to indicate the a particular cell has the same value as the last revision.  For example:

```
id | logical_id | revision | x | y | z | other
---+------------+----------+---+---+---+--------
 1 |     1      |     1    | 1 | 2 | 5 | blue
 2 |     2      |     1    | 3 | 5 | 9 | red
 3 |     1      |     2    | 9 |   |   |
 4 |     2      |     2    |   | 7 |   | orange
 5 |     1      |     3    |   | 6 |   |
 6       3      |     1    | 0 | 0 | 0 | white
```

I need a query that takes each logical_id and builds a row containing the latest entry for each field after the revision ("regular fields"), in this case `x`, `y`, `z`, and `other`.  The number of such fields is arbitrary although it is perfectly acceptable that the query would need to be modified based on what these fields actually are (and I expect it).

So for the above table, the output would be:

```
logical_id | x | y | z | other
-----------+---+---+---+--------
    1      | 9 | 6 | 5 | blue
    2      | 3 | 7 | 9 | orange
    3      | 0 | 0 | 0 | white
```

I found this question, "[Database: Select last non-null entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977398/database-select-last-non-null-entries)", which seems to be almost exactly the same as my question but the question is with regards to Postgresql, and the solutions given are either using language constructs not available in SQLite (FIRST_VALUE, PARTITION BY?), seem to only answer part of the problem (for instance, only finding the result for a single logical id), or when I tried them in SQLite they simply didn't work.

As an added bonus, I would also like to be able to mark a `logical_id` as being deleted by setting all "regular fields" to NULL, if that is possible.

Comment: Should the output really have `id` and `revision` columns? What should their values be?

Comment: @CL. You are right, those columns are not needed in the output. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look up the non-NULL value of the row with the largest revision for each logical ID, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT logical_id,
       (SELECT x
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE logical_id = T.logical_id
          AND x IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY revision DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS x,
       (SELECT y
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE logical_id = T.logical_id
          AND y IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY revision DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS y,
       ...
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT logical_id
      FROM MyTable
      -- WHERE ...
     ) AS T
```

Alternatively, it is possible to do this with GROUP BY, but to be able to get the actual column value when searching for the largest revision with MAX, it is necessary to combine the revision and the other value into a single string, and to extract the column value afterwards:

```
SELECT logical_id,
       substr(max(printf('%9d', revision) || x), 10) AS x,
       substr(max(printf('%9d', revision) || y), 10) AS y,
       ...
FROM MyTable
-- WHERE ...
GROUP BY logical_id
```

To remove logical IDs whose latest revision is all NULL, add a WHERE clause like this:

```
...
WHERE logical_id NOT IN (SELECT logical_id
                         FROM (SELECT logical_id,
                                      max(revision) AS revision
                               FROM MyTable
                               GROUP BY logical_id)
                         JOIN MyTable USING (logical_id, revision)
                         WHERE x     IS NULL
                           AND y     IS NULL
                           AND z     IS NULL
                           AND other IS NULL)
...
```

Comment: that certainly works but it is *slow*... over 6 seconds for 2000 rows. With that performance it seems it would be better to accept redundant data in each revision.

Comment: The first query can be sped up with a two-column index on `logical_id` and `revision`.

Comment: 98ms, that's quite an improvement.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

SQLite 3.25 introduced windowed functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  logical_id
 ,FIRST_VALUE(x) OVER(PARTITION BY logical_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN -1
                                                       ELSE id END DESC) AS x
 ,FIRST_VALUE(y) OVER(PARTITION BY logical_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN y IS NULL THEN -1
                                                       ELSE id END DESC) AS y
 ,FIRST_VALUE(z) OVER(PARTITION BY logical_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN z IS NULL THEN -1
                                                       ELSE id END DESC) AS z
 ,FIRST_VALUE(other) OVER(PARTITION BY logical_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN other IS NULL 
                                                THEN -1 ELSE id END DESC) AS other
FROM tab;
```

**[db-fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wkR7xzhZu9sPhYpRNhz8b8/0)**

Output:

```
+-------------+----+----+----+--------+
| logical_id  | x  | y  | z  | other  |
+-------------+----+----+----+--------+
|          1  | 9  | 6  | 5  | blue   |
|          2  | 3  | 7  | 9  | orange |
|          3  | 0  | 0  | 0  | white  |
+-------------+----+----+----+--------+
```